# Windows Mobile - Stop Main Phone App

Tags: c#, c++, windows-mobile, pinvoke, windows-mobile-5.0

Is there a way to make Windows Mobile not use the main phone app?  I have my own phone app that I want to handle phone transactions for a business device.

My app works fine (detects the call and can hang up), but the main phone app still wants to allow the user to answer a call normally.  I can try to hide the incoming call window or programmatically press the ignore key, but that is a bit clunky.

Basically, I need a way to make the built in phone app not know about incoming calls.

Any advice would be appreciated!

In case it matters I am using a Symbol MC70 running Windows Mobile 5.

Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks to djhowell's answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/30798/windows-mobile-5-stop-toast-popup-for-incomming-calls) I now know that the offending app is cprog.exe.  But apparently it is hard to kill because [services.exe keeps bringing it back](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsmobiledev/thread/82eef36d-7512-480a-96d6-0ba43d57556b).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you *should not* do it. Replacing system dialer will create you more troubles than you can expect.

If you still want to do it, there is no nice way to do it, even if you opt to use RIL directly. So, there is a trick in which you create a dummy cprog.exe (which does absolutely nothing), and put in the root folder . After the phone boots, that program will be started instead of the native one that is located in the \Windows folder. Then no program will be listening for incoming calls.

Comment: I can appreciate the "don't be evil" and "more trouble than it is worth" comments. But really I am just trying to lock my phone down. I don't want any user initiated outgoing or incoming calls. (This is a corporate device used for 'Non-Phone' activities. (But I still need the phone contract because I get a GPRS connection via the cellular line.)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend asking Symbol (actually Motorola), they may have insight into your problem. I work with MC3090's and they were helpful before.